# Catch broken pipe when returning through SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I'm trying to make my SOAP service more robust, and handle clients that disconnect while the method they called is still running. I'm using @WebService and javax.jws.WebService.

The problem is that the called code ignores the disconnecting client and continues running, and only fails *after* it tries to return. I'd like to reverse the processing done but don't know how to catch this exception as it's simply printed after the method returns.

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:101)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:249)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:328)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:82)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:470)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handleExchange(WSHttpHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.WSHttpHandler.handle(WSHttpHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:65)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:68)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:65)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:529)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.flush(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:388)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.streaming.XMLStreamWriterUtil.getOutputStream(XMLStreamWriterUtil.java:86)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:308)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:98)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:69)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:40)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:336)
    at sun.net.httpserver.Request$WriteStream.write(Request.java:397)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ChunkedOutputStream.writeChunk(ChunkedOutputStream.java:108)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ChunkedOutputStream.flush(ChunkedOutputStream.java:138)
    at sun.net.httpserver.PlaceholderOutputStream.flush(ExchangeImpl.java:395)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.UTF8OutputStreamWriter.flush(UTF8OutputStreamWriter.java:140)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.flush(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:386)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. Broken pipe means the client disconnected and the server tried to write to the closed socket. But the socket is not exposed in the web methods so I don't think it is catchable.

Comment: Could this be a bug with the JDK? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/+bug/995000